# Are temporary stateful filters possible in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have implemented a i18n localisation filter in AngularJS 1.4.x
The localizer loads the translations asynchronously.
This requires a $stateful filter.

However, after the translations are loaded and another digest-cycle the filter could revert back to non-stateful for better performance.

**Does AngularJS recognize if a filter changes from $stateful=true to $stateful=false, or is $stateful a constant?**

**How many instances of a filter are created in the factory (resetting $stateful must involve all instances)?**

References: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#stateful-filters